# How to create an array with size increasing with the iteration

Tags: python, arrays, list

I would like to create a list or array in python which has to append the value of a variable calculated at each of a for or while loop. For example, the variable calculated in python at each loop is `output@iteration1=2` , `output@iteration2=3` ,.... So I want to get `list_output=[2,3,...]`

Comment: How would this iteration know when to stop?

Comment: `for i in range(2, 4): lst.append(i)`

Comment: Domenico, if my answer helped you, I would appreciate it if you would accept it. It lets other people know that my answer works as a solution, and gives me rep. :) Thanks!

Comment: Morgan, thanks for your message. I think the next answer is exactly what I needed. By the way I appreciate your help.

Comment: @DomenicodiCugno In that case, would you mind accepting my answer? You just click the little check-mark under the voting arrows on my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your indication. I started to use this website quite recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
results = []
for value in values:
    results.append(value)
```

or, for bonus points, a list comprehension:

```
results = [value for value in values]
```